# Migrating from Linux to OSX and have a few questions

Tags: macbook-pro, unix

I've read [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16339/what-are-the-main-difficulties-people-face-migrating-from-linux-to-mac-os) question and still have a few concerns.

I've been using linux for a number of years and was wondering if some of the features I have learned to rely on are present in OSX (on a Macbook Pro, if it matters).

- Is OSX's terminal still BASH? And if it isn't, how easy is it for me to install it on my system?
- Will I be able to compile software (usually designed for Linux) on my mac and use it?
- How easy is it for me to dual-boot on a macbook (OSX & Linux)? Is it even possible?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! You have three questions here. This site works best with one question per question. That way, people can easily read and write answers. Please feel free to ask these questions separately. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.